# Direito sobre o código

Tags: licença

Imaginemos o seguinte cenário hipotético: Empresa X contrata um freelance para desenvolver um sistema, o freelance tem direito sobre o código? Por exemplo, se o freelance desejar vender o sistema no futuro?

E se forem feitas modificações no código original(que foi entregue ao cliente)?

Mas digamos que eu fui contratado para escrever o código. Eu fiz e entreguei o projeto ao cliente, depois eu reaproveito algumas coisas e faço um concorrente, isso é crime?

Comment: Depende de como o contrato é feito. O mais comum é que os direitos sobre o produto fiquem resguardados para o cliente, pois ele pagou por isso, mas existem cenários em que o contrato pode especificar, resguardando o direito do desenvolvedor revender o produto.

Comment: Esta questão esta sendo discutida no Meta: [É legal fazer perguntas sobre legislação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6041/3635)

Answer (score 17):

Não sei quanto a Portugal. Mas no Brasil, *software* enquanto propriedade é regido pela legislação de propriedade intelectual. É diferente dos Estados Unidos, por exemplo, onde software é regido pela legislação de patentes.

O seu caso é regido por uma lei própria para programas de computador, a [9609](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9609.htm).

O artigo quarto diz, e eu ponho ênfase nas partes relevantes:

> Art. 4º **Salvo estipulação em contrário**, pertencerão exclusivamente ao empregador, **contratante de serviços** ou órgão público, os direitos relativos ao programa de computador, desenvolvido e elaborado durante a vigência de contrato ou de vínculo estatutário, expressamente destinado à pesquisa e desenvolvimento, ou em que a atividade do empregado, **contratado de serviço** ou servidor seja prevista, ou ainda, que decorra da própria natureza dos encargos concernentes a esses vínculos.

Ou seja: se você não tiver um contrato estabelecendo a sua propriedade do software desenvolvido, o software é de quem te contratou para fazê-lo.

Se você fizer um software que não for para um cliente - um programa "de prateleira", ou um site seu, então vale o disposto na [lei 9610](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9609.htm), a lei de direitos autorais propriamente ditos. Ela estabelece que nesses casos a propriedade é exclusiva do autor.

Eu vi uma **edição recente na pergunta**. Foi adicionado o seguinte questionamento: e se eu fizer modificações no código? Se o código for propriedade sua, ou se for uma modificação feita para seu cliente porque ele assim pediu, não há problemas. Caso contrário você terá cometido um crime, mesmo que suas modificações não sejam executadas nas máquinas do detentor dos direitos sobre o código. Essa é uma parte na qual acredito que todas as legislações do ocidente concordam: modificações sobre um código do qual você não detém a posse são uma forma de pirataria.

Comment: Mas digamos que eu fui contratado para escrever o código. Eu fiz e entreguei o projeto ao cliente, depois eu reaproveito algumas coisas e faço um concorrente, isso é crime?

Comment: @Max23 Se você não tiver um contrato que diga explicitamente que **você** é o detentor dos direitos autorais do código, sim. Se quiser fazer algo para outro cliente é melhor começar um código novo do zero.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Minhas dúvidas foram sanadas.